# setup shell to default eshell

Tags: spacemacs, eshell, default

I am new to Spacemacs and eshell.

I try to open eshell via the default shortcut key `SPC '` but it opens the bash shell:

```
[wolfv@localhost ~]
$ message "hello"
bash: message: command not found...
```

I was expecting the eshell.

However, `SPC a s e` opens eshell as expected:

```
~ λ message "hello"
hello
```

I followed the install instructions on https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Btools/shell#default-shell

My ~/.spacemacs file has the following lines in dotspacemacs-configuration-layers:

```
 shell
 (shell :variables
        shell-default-height 30
        shell-default-position 'bottom)
```

and the following lines in defun dotspacemacs/user-config ():

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
          '((shell :variables shell-default-shell 'eshell)))
```

**UPDATE**

I found the problem by trouble shooting, but don't know how to fix it.

After restarting Spacemacs, shell-default-shell help says:

> shell-default-shell is a variable defined in ‘config.el’.
>   Its value is ‘ansi-term’

I was expecting its value to be ‘eshell’.

Apparently the above mentioned defun dotspacemacs/user-config () entry did not work.

How to make shell-default-shell value be ‘eshell’?

Answer (score 2):

**option 1: (better)**
edit `.spacemacs`:
inside:
`(defun dotspacemacs/user-load ())`
and:
`(setq shell-default-shell 'eshell)`

**option 2:**

You can try go directly into `$HOME/.emacs.d/layers/+tools/shell/config.el` and edit last points:

```
(defvar shell-default-shell (if (eq window-system 'w32)
                                'eshell
                              'ansi-term)
```

into:

```
'eshell
'eshell)
```

and after this, add into `.gitignore`: `./layers/+tools/shell/config.el`